# How to use one RewriteRule .htaccess to handle all request

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working on a web application that requires using .htaccess for URL rewriting. I want to pass all request to a single file.
How can i use a single RewriteRule to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work perfectly fine for you

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /path/to/file [L]
```

The RewriteCond ensures the static files aren't rewritten (ie. robots.txt, favicon.ico, img/potato.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RewriteRule that always matches:

```
RewriteRule ^ /path/to/the/file [L]
```

You might want to add a RewriteCond as well. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /app.php [L]
```

The RewriteCond ensures that urls that map to an actual static file in your web root do not get rewritten (ie. robots.txt, favicon.ico, img/potato.jpg )